# Display none if no image

Tags: php, image

How to make the code below to display none if no image?

```
  protected function DisplayPhoto($Sender) {
        $body = $Sender->EventArguments['Discussion']->Body;
        preg_match('#\<img(.+?)src=(.+?)\>#s', $body, $matches);
        $image = "src=" . $matches[2];
        echo '<img class="ProfilePhotoSmall"' . $image . '>';
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 protected function DisplayPhoto($Sender) {
            $body = $Sender->EventArguments['Discussion']->Body;
            preg_match('#\<img(.+?)src=(.+?)\>#s', $body, $matches);

            if(isset($matches[2])){
               $image = "src=" . $matches[2];
                 echo '<img class="ProfilePhotoSmall"' . $image . '>';
             }else{
                  //do what you want
                 }       
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do something along the lines of:

```
if (count($matches) == 0){
    //do whatever if no image is here
}else{
    //do whatever if there IS an image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected function DisplayPhoto($Sender) {
    $body = $Sender->EventArguments['Discussion']->Body;
    preg_match('#\<img(.+?)src=(.+?)\>#s', $body, $matches);
    $image = "src=" . $matches[2];
    if( strlen( $matches[2] ) > 0 ){
        echo '<img class="ProfilePhotoSmall"' . $image . '>';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code to:

```
protected function DisplayPhoto($Sender) {
    $body = $Sender->EventArguments['Discussion']->Body;
    preg_match('#\<img(.+?)src=(.+?)\>#s', $body, $matches);
    $image = "src=" . $matches[2];
    if(!(strlen( $matches[2] ) > 0)){
        echo '<img class="ProfilePhotoSmall"' . $image . '>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   If (strcmp($image,"src=")!=0)
      #print whatever you want
```

If $matches[2] your $images contain only "src=". If $images only contains "src=" than do nothing,else print whatever you want.

Comment: If ($matches[2] is empty,than $images will only be src=. If so print nothing,else print whatever you want.